# varchar(max) datatype odbc mapping to ms-access2003

Tags: ms-access, sql-server-2008

i have tested the difference between defining varchar(max) in opposite text with our legacy application on a SQL Server 2005. All went very well and the new datatype reduced in a particular test case the amount of reads from 78 to 8 that represents a performance gain which we dont want to miss.

But now on the target sqlserver of version 2008 i get a problem: the columns of datatype varchar(max) are now mapped to the **msaccess2003** datatype text(255).

Where is this odbc mapping defined? Which parameter must be changed to get the desired mapping varchar(max) to memo?

Peace

Ice

**Update:**

Now i know that when i connect the Access ODBC-Sources while remotely logged on the Win 2008 / SQL Server 2008 the mapping of varchar(max) to ms-access-datatype memo is correct.
We work in a LAN and while logged on the Win2003-Citrix-Server connecting the ODBC-Sources with ms-access the mapping goes wrong.
Very weird situation, whats is going on?

Comment: Sounds quite likely that the server's ODBC drivers are a different version than those on the workstations. I assume you're not under the impression that the server's ODBC drivers are used by connected client workstations, right? No one but those who are logged onto a session on the server is going to be using the server's ODBC drivers. Remember, this is Access with ODBC, which means it's Jet, and Jet uses your local machine's ODBC drivers.

Comment: @David: Yes, for shure i know these coherence. Therefore we have installed the SQL2008 Client-conectivity Tools on the client. There must be a difference but where to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this article refers to importing, it may be of interest to you: http://www.windows-tech.info/15/313c8cc3ac03f313.php

It states:

> Your field in SQL Server should be an
>   NVARCHAR(MAX) to map directly to the
>   MEMO field in Access. The data types
>   inside the SSIS package for that field
>   should be DT_NTEXT.

-- Phil Brammer

Comment: Our legacy application cannot handle unicode datatypes but i will giv it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Switching from Native SQL Server Native Client 10.0 to baked-in WinXP SQL Server driver for ODBC connection worked for me.

SQL Server 2008 varchar(max) now mapped to Access 2003 memo in my linked table.